# Phpmyadmin missing processes and privileges tabs

Tags: phpmyadmin

Installed WAMP:

- Win7
- Apache 2.4.4
- MySQL 5.6.12
- PHP 5.4.12

Logging in from a fresh restart of all services as a user or as root I am missing the Processes and Privileges tabs.  I may be missing more but those two I saw immediately when I had to try and kill a query.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The version of phpMyAdmin being used isn't listed in the question but at some point the "Privileges" tab was renamed to "Users" and the features on the old "Processes" tab were moved to the "Status" tab's sub tab labeled "Server".

As mentioned in the question the account being used must have the proper permissions to view these tabs.